# Downloading email attachment from MailBox using Pop3.dll in .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pop3, email-attachments

I am using vs 2010 for developing a winform application using c#.

For dowloading email attachments from mailbox i have used pop3.dll

my code download attachment when i use it on my machine which is direclty connected to internet but when i use it inside a domain where ISA server 2004 is used as a firewall my code only shows me how many message the mailbox box has and then goes for waiting

please can anybody tell me why and what should i do to resolve this problem..

here is the code

```
public bool DownloadEmailWithAttachment(string Type)
    {
        try
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", "Attachment Path :> " + AttachmentDir);
            long count = 0;
            Pop3Client email = new Pop3Client(UserName, Password, IncomingPopAddress);
            email.OpenInbox();                
            //LogEntry();
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", "Counter :> " + email.MessageCount);
            while (email.NextEmail())
            {
                count = email.MessageCount;
                if (email.IsMultipart)
                {

                    IEnumerator enumerator = email.MultipartEnumerator;
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        Pop3Component multipart = (Pop3Component)enumerator.Current;
                        string checkIfFile = multipart.Filename;

                        if (checkIfFile != null)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("checkIfFile.Contains('Leave') =" + checkIfFile.ToString());
                            EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", "checkIfFile.Contains('"+Type+"') =" + checkIfFile.ToString());
                            if (checkIfFile.Contains(""+Type))
                            {
                                EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", "Attachment name=" + multipart.Name); // ... etc
                                byte[] filebytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(multipart.Data);

                                //Search FileName
                                int fileLength = checkIfFile.Length;
                                EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", "fileLength=" + fileLength);
                                //int Begin = multipart.ContentType.IndexOf("name="+checkIfFile.ToString());
                                string leFileNale = checkIfFile.ToString();
                                EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", leFileNale);
                                FileStream LeFS = new FileStream(AttachmentDir + "\\" + leFileNale, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                                LeFS.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
                                LeFS.Close();
                                string DeleteMailContainingSubject = email.Subject.ToString();
                                if (email.Subject.Contains(DeleteMailContainingSubject))
                                {
                                    email.DeleteEmail();
                                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Service", "Email with Subject " + DeleteMailContainingSubject);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
            email.CloseConnection();
        }
        catch (Pop3LoginException ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Service","Exception :" + ex.ToString());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is my code for downloading email attachments.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6062/A-POP3-Client-in-C-NET    it is dll used to downloading email i have used alternative's like openpop3,mail.dll etc but same problem has been occurring

Comment: Theres a few possible issues: Firstly, the firewall could be blocking the attachments coming through. If that's the case.. you'll need to find out why. The other thing could be that it requires authentication so that it can enforce the rules against users. Since you're not authenticating it may be enforcing very strict rules.

Comment: Which kind of authentication do you mean and on which file, we are able to download email attachments from exchange server. while using code we are not able to download the attachments